# mysql copy data between table with parent child relation

Tags: mysql, vb.net

i have two identical table

the first table's structure is like a tree where each record acts like a node.

each node has three field consist of: **index** as the node-id, **item** as the represent of item name, **parents** as pointer to the previous node(index)..

as you can see at the picture each node related to each other based on their **parent-index** field relation

now what i wanna do is **traversing each node(record) to the root, then arrange them into a new table with the same structure**, so later on the 2nd table will have **21 records as seen on picture**

i'm using vb.net and for next looping to loop the index of each row, then insert each row into a new table.. but the problem is how can i ** copy the data from 1st table to 2nd table with condition parent-child **

here's the picture

[image]

here's my pseudocode

```
for i=1 to 11

checkindex = select * from 1st table where index = i

if checkindex.hasrows() then
traverse the row to its root then insert into 2nd table
end if

next i
```

so my question is, based on my pseudocode, how to code **traversing each row** then insert into 2nd table?

i'm using mysql database and vb.net

thanks for your attention

I'VE UPDATED MY CODED ACCORDING TO PSEUDOCODE FROM KJELL

```
For node = 1 To maxnode
        'QUERY A= FETCHING ROW/NODE FROM TABLE1 BASED ON INDEX
        Dim node1 As String = "select indeks, item, parent from tree where indeks = '" & node & "' "
        CMD_node = New MySqlCommand(node1, conn.konek)
        hasilnode = CMD_node.ExecuteReader()

        If hasilnode.HasRows Then
            'QUERY B = FETCH PARENT VALUE FROM CURRENT ROW
            Dim getpar1 As String = "select parent from tree where indeks = '" & node & "' "
            CMD_getpar = New MySqlCommand(getpar1, conn.konek)
            getpar = Convert.ToInt32(CMD_getpar.ExecuteScalar())

            'QUERY C = INSERT CURRENT ROW(TABLE1) TO TABLE2
            Dim rec_ins As String = "insert into node (indeks, item, parent, node_id) select indeks, item, parent, '" & node & "' from tree where indeks = '" & node & "' "
            CMD_recs = New MySqlCommand(rec_ins, conn.konek)
            CMD_recs.ExecuteNonQuery()
            CMD_recs.Connection.Dispose()

            'QUERY D = CHECKING IF CURRENT ROW'S PARENT = 0 (NOT EXIST) WITH PARENT VALUE ACHIEVED FROM QUERY B

            If getpar <> 0 Then
                'INSERT NEWROW WHERE NEWROW.INDEX = CURRENT ROW.PARENT
                Dim rec_ins2 As String = "insert into node(indeks, item, parent, node_id) select indeks, item, parent, '" & node & "' from tree where indeks = '" & getpar & "' "
                CMD_recs = New MySqlCommand(rec_ins2, conn.konek)
                CMD_recs.ExecuteNonQuery()
                CMD_recs.Connection.Dispose()
            End If
            'Else
            'Continue While
            'End If

            'End While

        Else
            Continue For
            CMD_getpar.Connection.Dispose()
        End If
        CMD_node.Connection.Dispose()

    Next node

    CMD_list.Connection.Dispose()
```

this code produce result just like my illustration **but** each current row in table1 **only** call the previous rows **once**, resulting like each row in table 1 (except row with parent 1) only generating two row in table2, **which is the desired result is supposed to be:** each row in table 1 generating different amount of rows in table2, according to **the parent-index relation**

for example row "3 A 2" in table1, supposed to be generating result in table2:

3 A 2

2 F 1

1 C 0

but my code only return like:

3 A 2

2 F 1

and the other rows generating the same result, **only** 2 rows

Comment: +1 for a visually pleasing question :).

Answer (score 0):

you will need a recursive function which is responsible for deep-copying the object like this:

- copy my content to table 2.
- check if i have a parent
- get the parent's content and start copy function with that content.

You should query table 1 for all your objects and in a loop call the recursive deep copy function.

hope this makes sense to you...

The recurvise function might look like:

```
function storeMe(content) {
  storeToDb(content)
  myParentID = content[parent]
  if (myParentID != 0) {
    parentContent = getParentContent(myParentID)
    unset(parentContent[lineID])
    storeMe(parentContent)
  }
}
```

The main functionality could look like:

```
myObjects = getAllFromTable1()
for(myObjects) {
  storeMe(object)
}
```

One crucial thing here: if your table1 uses a unique id for each line in the DB you have to unset it when storing the parents, so a new element is written to the DB and not the same updated over and over again.

Comment: in your first point: is it mean that i need to fill the 2nd table with exact same data from 1st table(my content) ?

could you please explain the recursive function part in pseudocode?

thanks for your help.

Comment: thanks you very much for the code @Kjell. i'll try to learn this first, :)

Comment: please correct my interpretation. is the  **getallfromtable** function stands for sql query to select all data from table 1.. (CMIIW). the storeme function stands for inserting the data to table2 with parent-child relation (CMIIW). and what does the storetodb and unset stands for?
thanks for your help by the way

Comment: storeToDb inserts one line into your second table. Unset is a function in php to delete something. in this case it deletes the line id from the content. This might be required depending on how you insert into the db.

Comment: hi @Kjell: could you help me again with the code? i've updated my question with a code. could you show me which query in my code should be turn into function like your pseudocode? (query A-D)
thx for your attention

Comment: dear @soni - your problem is, you are not using a recursive procedure or function - hence only the first parent is written to the DB. take a look [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/81tad23s.aspx) and try to implement a storeMe function like described above. Good luck!